# Can not convert table using dompdf in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I want to convert my HTML page to pdf but I can not do it. Maybe you know what I am doing wrong? Here is my code

web.php

```
Route::get('print/{id}',array('as'=>'htmltopdfview','uses'=>'ClientController@htmltopdfview'));
```

controller:

```
 public function htmltopdfview(Request $request)
{
    $products = Client::all();
    view()->share('products',$products);
    if($request->has('download')){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('client/print');
        return $pdf->download('client/print');
    }
    return view('client/print' compact('client'));
}
```

and view:

```
<a href="{{ route('htmltopdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>

            <div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::open(['action' => ['ClientController@doEdit', $client->id]]) !!}

                {!! Form::label('name', 'Imie i nazwisko:'); !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Edit!', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you **make a blade without that anchor tag**, **just keep plain html in your view i.e. blade**.I don't get the form part but you mostly need static page for that apart from accessing the products like

```
{{$products->id}}
```

Also for accessing the data in 
In **controller**, instead of returning view, return the below code right after the view()->share. I have mentioned below why you won't need that if condition

```
return $pdf->stream();
```

The download option will be automatically available in browsers like chrome. 
Also If you aren't using any data from request,why don't you try removing it.
**Also you never defined $client in that view**.

Comment: I did something like this:
public function htmltopdfview(Request $request)
{
    $products = Client::all();
    view()->share('products',$products);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('home');
return $pdf->stream(); 
    }

and my page is only loading and nothing more...